# API works with typescript but when I transpile it doesn´t find the model

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, babeljs, typeorm

I´m writing a simple API that Create, Read and Delete a student info in a postgres database.

When I use `ts-node-dev` without transpile the files to javascript, the App works. But when I transpile using babel and try to run `node dist/server.js` it gives this error:

```
(node:12771) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: /Users/Wblech/Desktop/42_vaga/src/model/Student.ts:1
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:681:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Function.PlatformTools.load (/Users/Wblech/Desktop/42_vaga/node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js:114:28)
    at /Users/Wblech/Desktop/42_vaga/node_modules/typeorm/util/DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.js:39:69
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.importClassesFromDirectories (/Users/Wblech/Desktop/42_vaga/node_modules/typeorm/util/DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.js:39:10)
(node:12771) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:12771) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The App runs, but if I do any http method it returns this error:

```
{
  "error": "No metadata for \"Student\" was found."
}
```

Just to be clear, the first error is in the terminal and after I do the command "node dist/server.js". The second error is when I try a http method, so the server runs but it doesn´t find my model Student.

The Student.ts is written this way:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity("students")
class Student {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("increment")
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column()
    intra_id: string;

    @Column("simple-array")
    projects: string;
}

export default Student;
```

and my ormconfig.ts is this:

```
{
    "type": "postgres",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5432,
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "docker",
    "database": "42sp",
    "entities": [
        "./src/model/*.ts"
    ],
    "migrations": [
        "./src/database/migrations/*.ts"
    ],
    "cli": {
        "migrationsDir": "./src/database/migrations"
    }
}
```

My package.json is this:

```
{
  "name": "42_vaga",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src --extensions \".js,.ts\" --out-dir dist --copy-files",
    "dev:server": "ts-node-dev --inspect --transpile-only --ignore-watch node_modules src/server.ts",
    "typeorm": "ts-node-dev ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.10.4",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.7",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata": "^0.3.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.51",
    "typescript": "^3.9.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.0.23",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "pg": "^8.3.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.4",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.25",
    "uuidv4": "^6.1.1"
  }
}
```

My babel config:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current'}}],
        '@babel/preset-typescript'
    ],
    plugins : [
        "babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata",
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true}],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true}],
    ]

}
```

My tree folder is like this:

```
├── README.md
├── babel.config.js
├── dist
│   ├── database
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   └── migrations
│   │       └── 1594744103410-CreateStudents.js
│   ├── model
│   │   └── Student.js
│   ├── repositories
│   │   └── StudentRepository.js
│   ├── routes
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   └── students.routes.js
│   ├── server.js
│   └── services
│       └── CreateStudentService.js
├── documentation.md
├── instructions.md
├── ormconfig.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── database
│   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   └── migrations
│   │       └── 1594744103410-CreateStudents.ts
│   ├── model
│   │   └── Student.ts
│   ├── repositories
│   │   └── StudentRepository.ts
│   ├── routes
│   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   └── students.routes.ts
│   ├── server.ts
│   └── services
│       └── CreateStudentService.ts
├── tsconfig.json
├── yarn-error.log
└── yarn.lock
```

I don´t get it  why it does work when is typescript but when is javascript it doesn´t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is in your ormConfig.ts

`{
"type": "postgres",

```
"host": "localhost",
"port": 5432,
"username": "postgres",
"password": "docker",
"database": "42sp",
"entities": [
    "./src/model/*.ts" // so here you specify the ts file but after transpile 
                       //  it will convert into js so you need to do some 
                       // correction here so that it can work in ts and js mode too
],
"migrations": [
    "./src/database/migrations/*.ts"
],
"cli": {
    "migrationsDir": "./src/database/migrations"
}
```

}`

just change the entities with below line of code :-

```
entities: [__dirname + "/../entities/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
```

so now it will work in work after transpile too.

Hope it will help